# Looking for Something Similar to Facebook's Unique Big Int IDs used in the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, identity, uniqueidentifier, api-design

What was is best practice for an enterprise architecture where you would like to assign every unique entity in the system an ID. And rather than a GUID you'd like to use a Big Int. Does anyone know what Facebook does internally to accomplish the goal?

In my situation some entities will be in MySQL, some in MongoDB, and later maybe some in Cassandra.

Do they have an "identity service" which hands out new IDs? An algorithmic method? I'm looking for what is simple, fast and scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do they have an "identity service" which hands out new IDs?

This is exactly what I would recommend. When well designed, it's fast, scalable, no dupes between different objects, etc.  However, when poorly designed, it's slow, not scalable, dupes are easy, etc.

Comment: Have you done something similar before? What kind of datastore did you use for the "id service". +1

Comment: I've used all sorts of dbs in the past that can support this "identity service"  I haven't come across one yet that cannot.  Happy coding!

Comment: @DMCS can you provide any tutorial or example link for generating facebook like identity service? so i can learn and implement it too, i cant seem to find any info on it.